# Why does my code replace all chars in my loop?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, nested-loops, cs50

I am trying to make a a loop that would make a stair case or half a pyramid if you will.
but whenever I print it all my # Chars get replaced by the $ chars returning solid rows of chars.

what Am I doing wrong in my (Int a) loop.
How do I make it return something like this:

```
        #
       ##
      ###
     ####
    #####
   ######
  #######
 ########
```

instead of solid blocks like this:

```
$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$
```

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
   int ask = 0;
   char line[9];

   while ( ask < 1 || ask > 8 ) {
      ask = get_int( "Height: ");
   }
   for (int i = 0 ; i < ask; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < ask; j++)
      {
        line[j] ='#';
         }
         for (int a = 0; a <= strlen(line); a++)
         {
            if (line[a] == '#'){
               line[a] = '$';
            }
         printf("%c", line[a]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want `$` then what is this for `line[a] = '$';`?

Comment: OT: the `<=`  in `a <= strlen(line)` is definitly  a problem.

Comment: You don't add any spaces for the empty columns. Also the `char line[9];` array is uninitialized. You don't really need the array, anyway.

Comment: Since `line` is not initialized, the first call to `strlen(line)` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not done such an assignment already for a very long time.:)

For starters there is no need to use an array to output the pattern.

Your array is uninitialized. So using the function `strlen` invokes undefined behavior.

And it is entirely unclear why there is present the symbol `'$'`.

The program can be written without using an array and the magic numbers `9` and `8`.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char c = '#';

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter the height (0 - exit): " );

        unsigned int n;

        if (scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0) break;

        if (INT_MAX < n) n = INT_MAX;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf( "%*c", n - i, c );
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++) putchar( c );
            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the height (0 - exit): 10

         #
        ##
       ###
      ####
     #####
    ######
   #######
  ########
 #########
##########

Enter the height (0 - exit): 9

        #
       ##
      ###
     ####
    #####
   ######
  #######
 ########
#########

Enter the height (0 - exit): 8

       #
      ##
     ###
    ####
   #####
  ######
 #######
########

Enter the height (0 - exit): 7

      #
     ##
    ###
   ####
  #####
 ######
#######

Enter the height (0 - exit): 6

     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######

Enter the height (0 - exit): 5

    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####

Enter the height (0 - exit): 4

   #
  ##
 ###
####

Enter the height (0 - exit): 3

  #
 ##
###

Enter the height (0 - exit): 2

 #
##

Enter the height (0 - exit): 1

#

Enter the height (0 - exit): 0
```

As for your question

> Why does my code replace all chars in my loop?

then what you do is what you get

```
if (line[a] == '#'){
   line[a] = '$';
}
printf("%c", line[a]);
```